# WCAG 2.0 AA validation background image error

Tags: html, css

Our pages fail wcag 2.0 AA validation when background images are disabled. (Due to background colour)

We want to keep the dark background we have at the moment, but make the background white if images are
disabled. Is the below a smart solution to the problem?

bg_top is the main background image. bg_secNavigation is the dark background as a gradient.

```
background-image: url(../images/bg_top.jpg), url(../images/bg_secNavigation.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-color: #fff;
background-position: center top, left top;
```

Comment: Please specify which WCAG 2.0 rule is violated now, and in which way. A URL would probably be needed to see the problem. Normally, background color should be dark when background images are, and doing otherwise seems to create accessibility problems, not solve them. (How can you set text color so that it works both against dark background and against white background?)

Answer (score 0):

How can you disable background images?

Why don't you have a div with a simple dark background and then in that same div you have your background images...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I just don't understand the question, it's to get the conversation going and trying to figure out what this person is trying to achieve.